# Trying to create a module for image management

Tags: 6

I would like to create an image manager for a running Drupal website. This page should be able to add and remove the images with its name and other attributes. How could I achieve this using Drupal modules ? I am new to drupal and I have good experience with PHP only.

The only thing I got to do with this image manager is to have the images in the front end dynamically. I am working with Drupal 6. This is my first module development. I could not find this module on modules page. Please give me suggestion to make some changes. Please see my code as follows:

iisimages.module

```
name = IIS images Manager
description = manages IIS images 
core = 6.x
```

iisimages.install

```
<?php 
 function issimages_install(){ } /** * Implements hook_uninstall(). */ 
 function issimages_uninstall(){ } /** * Implements hook_schema(). */ 
 function issimages_schema(){   
    $schema['issimages'] = array(
      'description' => 'Holds the schema of ISS images',
      'fields' => array(
        'id' => array(
          'description' => 'ID',
          'type' => 'serial',
          'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'title' => array(
          'description' => 'Title',
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '255',
          'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'datetime' => array(
          'description' => 'Date Time',
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '20',
          'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'position' => array(
          'description' => 'Position',
          'type' => 'int',
        // 'file_name' => array(
        //   'description' => 'File',
        //   'type' => 'varchar',
        //   'length' => '100',
        //   'not null' => TRUE,
        // ),
          'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'url' => array(
          'description' => 'URL',
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '255',
          'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'active' => array(
          'description' => 'Status of the item',
          'type' => 'int',
          'size' => 'tiny',
          'not null' => FALSE,
          'default' => 1,
        ),
        'created' => array(
          'description' => 'Created Date time',
          'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'modified' => array(
          'description' => 'Modified Date time',
          'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
      'primary key' => array('id'),
    );
    return $schema;
}
```

iisimages.module

```
<?php /** * Implements hook_init() */ 

$rows = array(); 

function iisimages_init(){ } 

/** * Implements hook_permission() */ 
function iisimages_perm(){   
    // return array('access iisimages manager' =>  array(
 //      'title' => t('Access IISimages Manager'),
    //   'description' => t('Permission for accessing the iisimages manager module.'),
 //    ),
 //  );
    return array('access iisimages content', 'create iisimages');
}

/**
* Implements hook_help()
*/

function iisimages_help($path, $arg){
  switch ($path) {
    case 'iisimages/manage':
      // Help text for the simple page registered for this path.
      return t('This section displays the list of Pages.');
  }
}

/**
* Implements hook_menu()
*/

function iisimages_menu(){
  $items['iisimages/summary'] = array(
    'title' => 'IIS Image Manager',
    'page callback' => 'iisimages_summary',
    'access arguments' => array('access iisimages manager'),
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );
  $items['iisimages/update'] = array(
    'title' => 'Toggle Status',
    'page callback' => 'iisimages_update',
    'access arguments' => array('access iisimages manager'),
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );
  $items['iisimages/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add Page',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('iisimages_add'),
    'access arguments' => array('access iisimages manager'),
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );
   $items['iisimages/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit Page',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('iisimages_edit'),
    'access arguments' => array('access iisimages manager'),
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );
  $items['iisimages/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete Page',
    'page callback' => 'iisimages_delete',
    'access arguments' => array('access iisimages manager'),
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function iisimages_summary($arg = 0){
  $result = db_query("select id, name, (select count(*) from iisimages a where b.id = a.id) count, active  from iisimages b where id=$arg");
  $rows = array();
  $i=0;
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $rows[] = array_map('check_plain', (array)$record);
    //Make name as hyperlink if it has some count value
    if($rows[$i]['count'] > 0){
         $rows[$i]['name']= l($rows[$i]['name'], 'iisimages/summary/'.$rows[$i]['id']);
    }
    //Make active value as standard icon
    $rows[$i]['active'] = $rows[$i]['active']==1
        ? l(theme('image', array('path' => drupal_get_path('module','iisimages').'/images/active.png', 'alt' => 'Active image', 'title' => 'Active',)),'iisimages/update',array('html' => TRUE, 'query' => array('id' => $rows[$i]['id'])))
        : l(theme('image', array('path' => drupal_get_path('module','iisimages').'/images/inactive.png', 'alt' => 'Inactive image', 'title' => 'Inactive',)),'iisimages/update',array('html' => TRUE, 'query' => array('id' => $rows[$i]['id'])));
    $rows[$i]['edit'] = l('Edit', 'pages/edit', array('query' => array('id' => $rows[$i]['id'])));
    if($rows[$i]['count'] == 0)
        $rows[$i]['delete'] = l('Delete', 'iisimages/delete', array('query' => array('id' => $rows[$i]['id'])));
    $i++;
  }
  $header = array(t('Id'), t('Name'), t('Total'), t('Active'),t('Edit'),t('Delete'));
  $output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
  $output .= l('Add Page', 'iisimages/add');
  //die(var_dump(get_defined_vars()));
  //ddebug_backtrace();
  return $output;
}

function iisimages_update(){
    $result = db_query("update iisimages set active = !active where id={$_GET['id']}");
    header("Location: summary");
}

function iisimages_delete(){
    $result = db_query("DELETE FROM iisimages where id={$_GET['id']}");
    header("Location: summary");
}

function iisimages_add($form, &$form_submit){
    $iisimages = getPages();
    $form['title'] = array(
        '#title' => t('IIS Image Title'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => t('Title of the image'),
    );

    $form['datetime'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Date Time'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE
    );

    $form['position'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Position'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#delta'=>50
    );


    $form['url'] = array(
        '#title' => t('URL'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE
    );


    $form['active'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Status'),
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
    );
    //kpr($form);
    return $form;
}

function iisimages_edit($form, &$form_submit){
    $iisimages = getPages();
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
        $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM iisimages WHERE id = {$_GET['id']}");
        $row = array();
        foreach($result as $record){
            $row = (array)$record;
        }
    }

    $form['id'] = array(
        '#value' => $row['id'],
        '#type' => 'hidden',
    );

    $form['title'] = array(
        '#title' => t('IIS Image Title'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => t('Title of the image'),
        '#default_value' => $row['title'],
    );

    $form['datetime'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Date Time'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => $row['datetime']
    );

    $form['position'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Position'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => $row['position'],
        '#delta'=>50
    );

    $form['url'] = array(
        '#title' => t('URL'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => $row['url'],
    );

    $form['active'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Status'),
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#default_value' => $row['active'],
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
    );
    //kpr($form);
    return $form;
}

function iisimages_add_submit($form, &$form_state){
    //kpr($form);exit;
    $title = $form_state['values']['title'];
    $datetime = $form_state['values']['datetime'];
    $position = $form_state['values']['position'];
    $url = $form_state['values']['url'];
    $active = $form_state['values']['active'];

    $result = db_query("INSERT INTO iisimages(title,position,url,datetime,active) VALUES('{$title}', {$position}, '{$url}', '{$datetime}', '{$active}') ");
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'iisimages/summary';
}

function getPages(){
    global $rows;
    $result = db_query("SELECT id, title, datetime FROM iisimages");
    $pages = array('ROOT');
    $i=0;
    foreach ($result as $record) {
        $record = (array)$record;
        $rows[] = $record;
        $pages[$record['id']] = $record['title']
        $i++;
    }
    return $pages;
}

function iisimages_edit_submit($form, &$form_state){
    //kpr($form);exit;
    $title = $form_state['values']['title'];
    $datetime = $form_state['values']['datetime'];
    $position = $form_state['values']['position'];
    $url = $form_state['values']['url'];
    $active = $form_state['values']['active'];

    $id = $form_state['values']['id'];
    $result = db_query("UPDATE iisimages SET title='{$title}',position={$position},url='{$url}',datetime='{$datetime}',active={$active}} WHERE id = {$id}");
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'iisimages/summary';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to drupal answers.what do you call image manager? A form to upload pictures? A gallery? You 'd better edit your question because I'm afraid it is too broad.

Comment: Please find the updated question